# Scroll to next and prev ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having a number of sections with different content and a link (prev and next) to go to the next section.

This is working fine, however when i am adding a new section in the middle I have to change ALL the ids so the next and prev button is still working fine.

Let's see this example:

```
<section id="uno" class="portfolio-item">
<div>my content</div>
<a class="next" href="#dos">Next</a>
</section>

<section id="dos" class="portfolio-item">
<div>my content</div>
<a class="back" href="#uno">Back</a>
<a class="next" href="#tres">Next</a>
</section>

<section id="tres" class="portfolio-item">
<div>my content</div>
<a class="back" href="#dos">Back</a>
<a class="next" href="#cuatro">Next</a>
</section>
```

Considering I don't want to do this manually because I am adding content usually and is not at the end always so I need to know how to automatize this using jQuery.

So, I don't want to add the id to each section and add manually the #link to the next/prev section.

How can I do this automatically? Detect the next section and just click on the next button without the need to add the name of each section (in the links and in the section).

Edited with the solution:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".next-new").attr("href", function(){
  return "#"+$(this).parents("section").next("section").attr("id");
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help to scroll next and prev dynamically created section

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".next").click(function(){
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(this).parent().next().offset().top
            }, 2000);
    });

     $(".back").click(function(){
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(this).parent().prev().offset().top
            }, 2000);
    });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<section id="uno" class="portfolio-item" style="height:300px">
<div>my content</div>
<a class="next">Next</a>
</section>

<section id="dos" class="portfolio-item" style="height:300px">
<div>my content</div>
<a class="back">Back</a>
<a class="next">Next</a>
</section>

<section id="tres" class="portfolio-item" style="height:300px">
<div>my content</div>
<a class="back">Back</a>
<a class="next">Next</a>
</section>

<section id="tres" class="portfolio-item" style="height:300px">
<div>my content</div>
<a class="back">Back</a>
<a class="next">Next</a>
</section>

<section id="tres" class="portfolio-item" style="height:300px">
<div>my content</div>
<a class="back">Back</a>
<a class="next">Next</a>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not working. Should be something like detect next section ID and add it dynamically to the link of next so is like #nameofnextid. Same with the prev. Thanks!

Comment: Added some code to explain better what I am trying to achieve

Comment: Great thank you. In my case I had to use parents instead of parent because the back and next were also inside a DIV. But is working fine now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try removing the hard coded section id and add it dynamically and the same with each section back and next button `href`  :

```js
$("section").each(function(i) {
  $(this).attr("id", i)

  //Back button
  var backButton = $(this).children().get(1);
  if (backButton.innerHTML == "Next") {
    $(backButton).attr("href", "#" + (i + 1))
    console.log(`Section id ${i} next element is ${(i + 1)} =>`, $(this).children().get(1))
  } else {
    $(backButton).attr("href", "#" + (i - 1))
    console.log(`Section id ${i} back element is ${(i - 1)} =>`, $(this).children().get(1))
  }

  var nextButton = $(this).children().get(2);
  if (nextButton) {
    $(nextButton).attr("href", "#" + (i + 1))
    console.log(`Section id ${i} next element is ${(i + 1)} =>`, $(this).children().get(2))
  }


})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class="portfolio-item">
  <div>my content 1 </div>
  <a class="next" href="#dos">Next</a>
</section>

<section class="portfolio-item">
  <div>my content 2</div>
  <a class="back" href="#uno">Back</a>
  <a class="next" href="#tres">Next</a>
</section>

<section class="portfolio-item">
  <div>my content 3</div>
  <a class="back" href="#dos">Back</a>
  <a class="next" href="#cuatro">Next</a>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is not what I need. I just need to be able to change the HREF dinamically detecting the ID of the next section so all the links would work without being necessary to add the name of the id manually. Is that possible? Thanks!

Comment: I added some code to explain better what I am trying to achieve.